# Verify whether substring of column A matches with substring in column B in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, match, substr

I have the following dataframe with news text (column Text) and the query (column Query) that I run to extract that specific news text from an API. Not all news texts are relevant to the query so I am trying to create a new column that returns True if at last part of the Query string is within the Text column. I know how to check whether the whole Query string is in the text, but as you see, often the official company name e.g. Nike Ltd. is not how news text report it (they may use more informal abbreviations).

It is a sort of fuzzy matching and I have not really figure out how to solve it.

```
news = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water before eating the meal'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian'], 'Query' :['Nike Ltd.', "LV", 'dog central']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)
```

Desired Outcome:

```
desired = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water before eating the meal'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian'], 'Query' :['Nike Ltd.', "LV", 'dog central'], 'Outcome':[True, False, True]}
desired _df = pd.DataFrame(desired )
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote *part of the Query string is within the Text column*, but we shoud
set some limits to this statement.

E.g. a **single letter** is also a part of the string, but we should not look
for such cases.

You should also treat "better" cases when e.g. 3 words from *Query* have been
matched in *Text* than a match for a **single** word.

Taking the above into account, I think, a more reasonable approach is to:

- split *Query* into words,
- count how many of these words have matches in *Text* (multiple
  occurrences should be still counted as one) - this is the result for
  the current row,
- apply the above procedure to each row in *news_df*.

The code to do it can be as follows:

```
import re

def hasMatch(t1, t2):
    cnt = 0
    for wrd in filter(lambda tt: len(tt) > 0, re.split(r'[^a-z]', t2, re.I)):
        if re.search(wrd, t1):
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

desired_df = news_df.copy()
desired_df['Outcome'] = desired_df.apply(lambda row: hasMatch(row.Text, row.Query), axis=1)
```

In this case the *Outcome* column is of *int* type (not *bool*), but I think
it is beter than *bool*.

Or if for you it is enough to find **any** match (even a single word) and
you don't care about the number of such matches, change the above function
so that it returns *bool* values instead of *int*.

Comment: this is great feedback and very well thought. I also was concerned about the idea of what is 'part of a string'. Thanks again!

Comment: one thing, when I test it I get some problems with escaping specific characters: an unbalanced parentheses in position  #. how can I make sure it escapes these kinds of problems? Right now I am just forcing with try and except

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using lambda

The below logic can help you to achieve the required output

```
news = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water before eating the meal'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian'], 'Query' :['Nike Ltd.', "LV", 'dog central']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)
news_df['Outcome'] = news_df.apply(lambda row: bool(len(set(row['Query'].lower().split(' '))) != len(set(row['Query'].lower().split(' ')) - set(row['Text'].lower().split(' ')))),axis=1)
```